# React Native Apollo error: Network request failed

Tags: javascript, react-native, graphql, apollo

I've tested my query on the GraphQL Playground and it works well. But when I try to get data from the client I am getting a "Network request failed" Error.
Please help!

Here is my code on React Native:

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, View, Text, TextInput } from "react-native";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";

const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: new HttpLink({
        uri: "http://localhost:5000/graphql",
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

function App() {
    return (
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
            <TestComp />
        </ApolloProvider>
    );
}

const testQuery = gql`
    {
        getPosts {
            username
        }
    }
`;

const TestComp = () => {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(testQuery);
    if (loading) {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center",  alignItems: "center", }} >
                <Text>Loading</Text>
            </View>
        );
    } else if (error) {
        return (
            <View>
                {console.log(error)}
                <Text>Error</Text>
            </View>
        );
    } else {
        console.log(data);
    }
};

export default App;
```

and this is the Error I get:

```
Network request failed
* http://172.20.10.2:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:172013:29 in ApolloError
- node_modules/@apollo/client/core/core.cjs.js:1461:35 in utilities.asyncMap$argument_2
- node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs.js:957:42 in Promise$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:45:6 in tryCallTwo
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:200:22 in doResolve
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:66:11 in Promise
- node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs.js:956:22 in <anonymous>
- node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:139:8 in notifySubscription
* http://172.20.10.2:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:151811:22 in onNotify
- node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:239:11 in error
* [native code]:null in forEach
- node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/utilities.cjs.js:944:4 in iterateObserversSafely
* http://172.20.10.2:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:171414:34 in error
- node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:139:8 in notifySubscription
* http://172.20.10.2:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:151811:22 in onNotify
- node_modules/zen-observable/lib/Observable.js:239:11 in error
* http://172.20.10.2:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:171934:24 in <unknown>
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
- node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

This is the Error I get on the terminal.
Stack Overflow says that I have to add some more Text to post this question so I am adding some more Text right now that has nonsense. Sorry for that.

Comment: Unless you're running a web server on the mobile device running this code, you shouldn't use `localhost` as the address for your server.

Answer (score 0):

if your graphql server running on local machine and your physical devices is also connected to same machine then use [  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql' ], I am using 4000 port. if you use another port mention that  port in uri link.

to solve this issue : on terminal use command  -- adb reverse tcp:4000 tcp:4000
use your port number instead of 4000. then restart your react native server.

in my case i try all solution give by stack overflow and google.
i use machine Ip address instead of localhost that also not work.